# How to convert an Image to UIImage?

Tags: image, uiimage, swiftui

How I can convert a SwiftUI `Image` to a `UIImage`?

```
let image = Image(systemName: "circle.fill")
let UIImage = image as UIImage
```

Comment: hi @nOK , why you need that? and what you want to achieve?

Comment: `UIImage` is part of `UIKit`, not `SwiftUI`. What *exactly are you trying to do? without SwiftUI, you can easily - via things very documented - *convert* between `UIImage, `CGImage`, and `CIImage`. If you consider that `Image` is *much* more like a `UIImageView`, again, what are you really looking for?

Comment: I was trying to save an image in CoreData and with UIImage I could easily just use image.pngData() but haven't found a possibility for images in swiftUI

Comment: Also variables of type "Image" don't seem to be conforming to the "Hashable" prototype

Answer (score 37):

There is no direct way of converting an Image to UIImage. instead, you should treat the Image as a View, and try to convert that View to a UIImage.
Image conforms to View, so we already have the View we need. now we just need to convert that View to a UIImage.

We need 2 components to achieve this. First, a function to change our Image/View to a UIView, and second one, to change the UIView we created to UIImage.

For more Convenience, both functions are declared as Extensions to their appropriate types.

```
extension View {
// This function changes our View to UIView, then calls another function
// to convert the newly-made UIView to a UIImage.
    public func asUIImage() -> UIImage {
        let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: self)
        
 // Set the background to be transparent incase the image is a PNG, WebP or (Static) GIF
        controller.view.backgroundColor = .clear 
        
        controller.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: CGFloat(Int.max), width: 1, height: 1)
        UIApplication.shared.windows.first!.rootViewController?.view.addSubview(controller.view)
        
        let size = controller.sizeThatFits(in: UIScreen.main.bounds.size)
        controller.view.bounds = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size)
        controller.view.sizeToFit()
        
// here is the call to the function that converts UIView to UIImage: `.asUIImage()`
        let image = controller.view.asUIImage()
        controller.view.removeFromSuperview()
        return image
    }
}

extension UIView {
// This is the function to convert UIView to UIImage
    public func asUIImage() -> UIImage {
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: bounds)
        return renderer.image { rendererContext in
            layer.render(in: rendererContext.cgContext)
        }
    }
}
```

**How To Use?**

```
let image: Image = Image("MyImageName") // Create an Image anyhow you want
let uiImage: UIImage = image.asUIImage() // Works Perfectly
```

**Bonus**

As i said, we are treating the Image, as a View. In the process, we don't use any specific features of Image, the only thing that is important is that our Image is a View (conforms to View protocol).
This means that with this method, you can not only convert an Image to a UIImage, but also you can convert any View to a UIImage.

```
var myView: some View {
// create the view here
}
let uiImage = myView.asUIImage() // Works Perfectly
```

Comment: How should I change the line `UIApplication.shared.windows.first!.rootViewController?.view.addSubview(controller.view)` for iOS 15? I get the deprecation warning: `"'windows' was deprecated in iOS 15.0: Use UIWindowScene.windows on a relevant window scene instead"`.

Comment: @Rillieux - Like this. Of course you could guard, etc. as well. But simply:

let scene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene
        scene?.windows.first?.rootViewController?.view.addSubview(controller.view)

Answer (score 27):

Such thing is not possible with SwiftUI, and I bet it will never be. It goes against the whole framework concept. However, you can go the opposite direction:

```swift
let uiImage = UIImage(systemName: "circle.fill")
```

```swift
let image = Image(uiImage: uiImage)
```

Comment: Variables of type "Image" don't seem to be conforming to the "Hashable" prototype that's why I was hoping to be able to convert it :/

Comment: If you would like to get the data from an `Image` view, you do not get it from the `Image` itself, but from the same place the Image got it. For example, if you load the Image using a uiImage object, you should go to that uiImage object. If the view got the image from a file name, you should go get it from the file. You will **never** be able to interrogate Image for its binary, it is not the way the framework is designed.

Comment: Thx for the help. I was kinda trying to avoid that but thought it might come to that :D Let's rewrite the code then :D

Comment: @kontiki Why it goes againts the whole framework concept?

Answer (score 14):

Try to add extension on View like so:

```
extension Image {
    @MainActor
    func getUIImage(newSize: CGSize) -> UIImage? {
        let image = resizable()
            .scaledToFill()
            .frame(width: newSize.width, height: newSize.height)
            .clipped()
        return ImageRenderer(content: image).uiImage
    }
}
```

And your use case will be

```
    let image = Image("someFromAssets")
    let size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
    let uiImage = image.getUIImage(newSize: size)
```

Comment: this should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 5):

As of iOS 16 and MacOS 13, most answers above are out of date. The answer now is to use ImageRenderer, which is designed to transform Views -- including Image -- to both UIImage and CGImage.

The main caveat is that ImageRenderer wants to run in the main thread, so you'll need to use GCD to get the image converted.

```
public func convert(image: Image, callback: @escaping ((UIImage?) -> Void)) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let renderer = ImageRenderer(content: image)

        // to adjust the size, you can use this (or set a frame to get precise output size)
        // renderer.scale = 0.25
        
        // for CGImage use renderer.cgImage
        callback(renderer.uiImage)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

#### iOS 16

```
extension View {
    /// Usually you would pass  `@Environment(\.displayScale) var displayScale`
    @MainActor func render(scale displayScale: CGFloat = 1.0) -> UIImage? {
        let renderer = ImageRenderer(content: self)

        renderer.scale = displayScale
        
        return renderer.uiImage
    }
    
}
```

Things to note:

1. @MainActor operation with ImageRenderer
2. Passing correct `.displayScale`
3. Will cause error if we try to render the view that's onscreen (see Note in comments).

#### iOS 15 and below

```
extension View {
    func snapshot() -> UIImage {
        let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: self)
        let view = controller.view
        
        let targetSize = controller.view.intrinsicContentSize
        view?.bounds = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: targetSize)
        view?.backgroundColor = .clear
        
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: targetSize)
        
        return renderer.image { _ in
            view?.drawHierarchy(in: controller.view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        }
    }
}
```

#### Usage

```
struct RenderView: View {
    let text: String
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(text)
            .font(.largeTitle)
            .foregroundStyle(.white)
            .padding()
            .background(.blue)
            .clipShape(Capsule())
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var text = "Your text here"
    @State private var uiImage = UIImage(systemName: "photo")
    @Environment(\.displayScale) private var displayScale
    
    var body: some View {
        let renderedImage = Image(uiImage: uiImage!)
        let textField = TextField("Enter some text", text: $text)
            .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
            .padding()
            .background(.blue)
            .clipShape(Capsule())
        
        VStack {
            renderedImage
            
            ShareLink("Export", item: renderedImage, preview: SharePreview(Text("Shared image"), image: renderedImage))

            textField

        }
        .onChange(of: text) { _ in
            uiImage = RenderView(text: text).render(scale: displayScale)!
            // Note that the following will not work for some reason
            // uiImage = textField.render(scale: displayScale)!
            
            // This kind of works, but rendered size differs from original
            // uiImage = textField.snapshot()
        }
    }

}
```

Credits go to [Paul Hudson](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-convert-a-swiftui-view-to-an-image).

Answer (score 0):

I have been using a wrapper as a workaround to achieve this

```
struct AppImage: View {
    private let name: String

    var body: some View {
        Image(name)
    }

    var asUIImage: UIImage? {
        UIImage(named: name)
    }
}
```

If you want to download an image from the internet, you can use [Kingfisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher) to achieve the same output.

```
import UIKit
import Kingfisher

struct AppImage: View {
    private let urlString: String

    var body: some View {
        KFImage(URL(string: urlString))
    }

    var asUIImage: UIImage {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.kf.setImage(with: URL(string: urlString))
        return imageView.image ?? UIImage(named: "placeholder-image")!
    }
}
```

Later on you can use any Image in your app as a `UIImage` if you stick to the `AppImage` type when initialising your images:

`AppImage(name: "image-name").asUIImage`

or
`AppImage(urlString: "https://url-to-your-image.com").asUIImage`