# How to convert SwiftUI Image back to UIImage?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uiimage

SwiftUI `Image` has an initializer to init an `Image` instance with an `UIImage` instance via `init(uiImage: UIImage)`. Is there a way to convert the Image instance back to `UIImage` type?

I found a similar question in [How to convert a image to UIImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57028484/how-to-convert-a-image-to-uiimage) but it does not answer my question. The motivation is that I need to save the Image to photo album via `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(_:_:_:_:)`

Obviously we can have another variable to hold the data source, the original `UIImage`, but I just wonder if that is really necessary.

Comment: Do you actually need a `UIImage`? Would a `UIView` not be sufficient?

Comment: Hey David, i updated my question. I need UIImage to save it to photo album

Comment: How are you creating the SwiftUI `Image`? And what code are you trying to use to save to photo album? Maybe there is an alternative that takes `Data` instead of a `UIImage`.

Comment: Yes, you should only have an `Image` for the purposes of displaying something in SwiftUI. The thing that you save to the photo album will need to come from your original source.

Comment: thanks @Paulw11 and @David. it sounds like `Image` is a dead-end once it is initiated so no data can be extracted from it any more